# MacBook Pro 16" M1 Pro computer no longer wakes up external monitor when waking itself

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, sleep-wake, apple-silicon

I have a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) with M1 Pro chip, hooked up to a 32" BenQ monitor. This setup worked well until updating to macOS Monterey 12.6.

Since that .6 update, when I press my finger on the Touch ID, the MacBook wakes its own screen but fails to wake the sleeping external monitor.

As a workaround, I merely unplug the USB-C/Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable from the MacBook, and plug it back in. The external monitor instantly wakes, the Mac recognizes the external monitor, and windows move back into place on the external.

Apple has a Support page, [*If your external display isn't detected or appears blurry when connected to your Mac*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201177). Does not address my problem.

In the olden days, we could display an icon menu for monitors. That menu offered a menu item to force the Mac to check for the presence of monitors. Very handy for trying to get projectors to work. Unfortunately, this feature seems to have disappeared in the modern macOS.

Is there any fix for this failure to wake the external monitor when the Mac wakes? As there any software workaround rather than me having to reach around to unplug and replug the cable?